# restful web API .net5 console app cannot start in windows server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I created an restful web api in .net5, I can run the console app after my built under bin\Debug\net5.0 and my console app starts like below;

[image]

This is nice because IIS not needed, But when I transfer my app to the production server which is windows server 2016, the console window opens then closes suddenly (same with administrator mode),
I also installed .net runtime from here [.net5 runtime download link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-5.0.10-windows-x64-installer)

but still same, could please advise me?  this is first time i try developing app using .net5

startup.cs :

```
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add logging to your app so you can catch startup errors, in the Program.cs.

Comment: I reinstalled .net runtime then it solved